# after Swift 2 migration, obj c programs can't see Swift programs

Tags: ios, swift, migration, swift2

The migration went pretty well for the most part, except that now, in every place one of my custom Swift classes is referenced in an Objective C class, the Swift class is not recognized.

Here is a sample:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SubscriptionController *subscriptionController;
```

This error results: 'Unknown type name 'SubscriptionController'

As before, this import resides near the top of all such files:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

Also, under Build Settings >> Swift Compiler - Code Generation >> Objective C Generated Interface Header Name, MyProject-Swift.h is still listed.

I watched the WWDC video "What's New in Swift 2", and searched for similar cases on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but so far have found nothing specific to this problem. Has the way to make Objective C programs see Swift programs changed? I'd be grateful for any insight on how to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the solution turns out to be simple. The Issue Navigator shows all of these errors about not recognizing the Swift classes. Well, a simple Build wiped out all of those errors and showed the real errors that were unresolved. I feel a bit silly, but there you go!